# distribute rows of vector with mpi

Tags: c++, mpi, genetic-algorithm

I have a genetic algorithm that I want parallel it with mpi. I have a 2d vector of a my genetic datatype and I want to distribute Blocks of two-dimensional vector lines between multiple nodes, I’ve used scatterv function but I don’t know this function is right or maybe I don’t set right parameters of this funcion. indivisual defined as a public parameter in GMC class std::vector individual[108];  Please help me.

Thanks

My code as below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

GMC(GraphName, 125);
int size, rank,divided_pop_size,sum=0;

vector<vector <int>> recbuf;
int *sendcounts;     //specifying the number of elements to send to each processor
int *displs;         //Entry i specifies the displacement 
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
printf("Hello world from process %d of %d\n", rank, size);
sendcounts = new int[size];
displs = new int[size];
divided_pop_size = n_initial_pop*num_vertices / size;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sendcounts[i] = (divided_pop_size);

    displs[i] = sum;
    sum += sendcounts[i];
}

recbuf.resize(divided_pop_size);
if (rank == 0)
{
    read_graph();
    vertex_degrees();
    initial_population();
}

MPI_Scatterv(&individual, sendcounts, displs, MPI_INT, &recbuf, sendcounts[rank] , MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if (rank==0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("sendcounts[%d] = %d\tdispls[%d] = %d\n", i, sendcounts[i], i, displs[i]);
    }
}
printf("%d: ", rank);
for (int i = 0; i < sendcounts[rank]; i++) {
    printf("%c\t", recbuf[i]);
}
/*
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    //MPI_Recv()//a
    //MPI_Recv()//indivual/size

    for (int i = 0; i < divided_pop_size; i++)
    {
        //Extend_into_MaximalClique(i);
        //fitness(i);
    }
}
if (rank == 0)
    //MPI_Gatherv();
    */
MPI_Finalize();

for (int j = 0; j < n_initial_pop; j++)
{
    //manipulation_Gen();
}




return 0;
```

}

Comment: Have you considered looking at the result and trying to fin out if you have correct result ? My advice on using MPI / any other distributed computing systems. First read about its methods and pick the one that fits your problem. Next learn how to use certain method (in this case `MPI_Scatterv`) on some simple, easy to test example problem, then try to apply it in real life scenario.

Comment: Some parameters are not defined in the code, in particular the `individual` in the `MPI_Scatterv`. It's difficult to know if data are passed as wanted without it, and without more explication on the scattering searched.

Moreover, the amount of passed data is the same for each processor, so `MPI_Scatter` can be an easier function to use here

Comment: `&somevec` where `somevec` is `std::vector<sometype>` most liekly won't render the result you'd expect. You should use `somevec.data()` (C++11) instead or `&somevec[0]` (pre-C++11).